# Azure Functions with node.js, Azure Service Bus and Apps Insight - Error on setup of AppsInsights

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

When I use azure module (to query Service Bus) and Application Insights module, I get the following error upon initialization of AppsInsight:

`System.Exception : Error: Zone already loaded. at new Error (native) at Error.AppInsightsAsyncCorrelatedErrorWrapper`

The code to replicate it is very simple:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(<Service Bus Endpoint>);

const appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup(<Apps Insight key>).start();
```

The error is thrown on the last line and I assume is a result of dependencies overlapping between azure and applicationinsights module.

Any suggestions how to overcome this are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I created my JavaScript HttpTrigger function to check this issue. I used **applicationinsights (version 0.22.0)** and I could reproduce this issue as follows:

[image]

**package.json:**

```html
{
  "name": "functions-app-insights",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "applicationinsights": "^0.22.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.8"
  }
}
```

Then I checked the [applicationinsights](https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights)  package and call `appInsights.setAutoDependencyCorrelation(false)`, then it could work as expected as follows:

[image]