# How to trigger a failure in an azure function http trigger, WITH a custom error response

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I cannot find a way to fail a http call to a nodejs azure function, and include a custom error response.

Calling context.done() allows for a custom response (but not indicated as a failure in Application Insights)

Calling context.done(true, XXX) does create a failure, but returns a generic error to the user (no matter what I put in XXX):

```
{"id":"b6ca6fb0-686a-4a9c-8c66-356b6db51848","requestId":"7599d94b-d3f2-48fe-80cd-e067bb1c8557","statusCode":500,"errorCode":0,"message":"An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID b6ca6fb0-686a-4a9c-8c66-356b6db51848"}
```

This is just the latest headache I have ran into in trying to get a fast web api running on Azure funcs. If you cant track errors, than it should hardly be called "Application Insights". Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Success will be true, but **resultCode** will be set to your value.

Try an AppInsights query like this:

```
// Get all errors
requests
| where toint(resultCode) >= 400
| limit 10
```

[Update] 
The Id value in Requests is the 'function instance id', which uniquely identifies that invocation.

There is also a 'traces' table that contains the logging messages from your azure function. You can join between requests and traces via the operation_Id.

```
requests 
| where toint(resultCode) >= 400
| take 10 
| join (traces) on operation_Id 
| project id, message, operation_Id
```

The response body is not automatically logged to AppInsights. You'll need to add some explicit log statements to capture that.

Comment: That lists rows of requests, but no links to trace logs like the "failures" view has. Basically no useful information for deugging, other than a count of fails.

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to get to trace logs and join against requests.

Comment: Also is that even part of "Application Insights". I cant get to the "analytics" query page from app insights. It seems to be a totally different service. Why does MS have to be so confusing? Wow, once you find a button that says "Analytics" and click it, it takes you to a page labeled "Application Insights", which is unreachable from the actual "Application Insights" dashboard.

Comment: It also appears that every trace in this view has the exact same millisecond timestamp, which means they cannot be ordered. Any idea how to project the timestamp of the actual trace?

Comment: Accepting this as the best answer, but still feel like you should be able to trigger a failure AND set a custom message, as opposed to not triggering a failure, and searching analytics for error resultCodes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `context.res` to return a customer response for an HTTP trigger function?

[image]

Comment: That is fine for the user, but leaves you no way to track errors in application insights. It's considered a success. If you put a truthy value in the done() then it tracks as error but ignores your body and substitutes the bs response.

Comment: To setup Application Insights for an Azure function, please check out [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/App-Insights-(Preview)) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153008/azure-functions-with-node-js-azure-service-bus-and-apps-insight-error-on-setu/46167895#46167895).

Comment: I'm attempting to use the predefined "failures" view in the portal. I get that I could install a bunch of libraries and do custom event throws, but it seems to me that tracking failed requests should be something built into a "serverless" hosting environment.